# Select seach text in PDF file using WebKit & swift

Tags: pdf, webkit, highlight

I use SQLite to search reference information of products related to a PDF Catalog file. Present the results in a Table View and when the user select one, show the PDF Catalog in the page of the product selected.

The problem is how i can highlight the reference found (is text)? I show the PDF file with WebKit.

Comment: What does this question have to actually do with SQLite?

Comment: Is only to know the situation. The question is How can highlight text in the PDF show with WebKit